# How to return complex JSON object from asp.net mvc Action Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, that connects to two different DB (I name them dbA & dbB). Currently I need to create a JSON object that contains values from different tables.

The two table are as follow:-

`Table Technology from dbA`, have the following fields:-

```
>> dbAID , Tag , db2ID
```

While `table Resource` from dbB have:-

```
>> Db2ID , Name
```

I have the following Action method:-

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term)

        {

var tech = dbA.Technology.Where(a=>a.Tag.StartWith(term));//select all technology that have their tags start with passed term

var db2IDList = tech.Select(a=>a.db2ID).ToArray();//create a list of db2ID



var resource = dbB.Resource.Where(db2IdList.Contains(a=>a.dbBID));//get the resource based on the db2IDList



JsonResult j = newJsonResult();

//here I want the json to contain the Technology.Tag + ResoruceNane, where the join is based on the db2Id stored insdie the technology table



        }
```

So can anyone adivce what is the best way to construct my JSON object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous Types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

And the framework provided JsonResult, generated by the Json(object) helper.

e.g. `return Json(new { field1 = resource.fieldOne, field2 = resource.fieldTwo })`

Comment: but what is resource.fieldOne and resource.fieldTwo ??

Comment: From your question: var resource = dbB.Resource.Where(db2IdList.Contains(a=>a.dbBID));//get the resource based on the db2IDList

Comment: but how the two fields will be linked together ?

Answer (score 0):

you can construct a List i think its easier :

```
List<Object> _return=new List<object>();
_return.Add(Technology.Tag);
_return.Add(ResoruceName);
Return Json(new {Success=true, _return});
```

//and then cast get these object in your Javascript , it would be an easy to use array

Comment: but will this approach join the two lists, i mean how i will know which tag relates to which resource name ?